# TypeError: "'str' object cannot be interpreted as integer using" Python's dpkt and socket modules

Tags: python, sockets, networking, typeerror, dpkt

Hello sorry of this is a dumb question but I'm trying to send an ICMP echo packet using the socket module's sendto() function. My socket is defined as:

```py
def make_socket(timeToLive, timeout):

    mySocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    mySocket.settimeout(timeout)
    mySocket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_TTL, timeToLive)
    return mySocket
```

I then create an ICMP echo packet inside the following function and try to send it, but this is where I'm getting the type error:

```py
def send_echo(socket, pay, id, seq, dest):
    echo = dpkt.icmp.ICMP.Echo()
    echo.id = id
    echo.seq = seq
    echo.payload = bytes(pay, 'utf-8')
    
    icmp = dpkt.icmp.ICMP()
    icmp.type = dpkt.icmp.ICMP_ECHO
    icmp.data = echo
    icmp_packed = icmp.pack()
    socket.sendto(icmp_packed, dest)
```

The problem is the last line `socket.sendto(icmp_packed, dest)` producing the error

```
line 42, in send_echo
    socket.sendto(icmp_packed, destination)
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I guess I'm a little confused on what's producing this error, because `icmp_packed` is of type `<class 'bytes'>` which is correct and `dest` is defined in my main function as:

```py
def main():
    host_port = tuple(["127.0.0.1", "65432"])
    send_icmp_echo(make_socket(5,5), "data", 5, 5, host_port)
```

keep in mind these values are just for testing purposes. I'm just trying to get it to compile at the moment. Is the type error caused from the `icmp_packed` or `dest` in `socket.sendto`? I used `bytes(pay, 'utf-8'` to convert the payload into class `bytes` but that didn't seem to help at all. Or is this a bug in my definitions? Any clarification/help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `host_port = tuple(["127.0.0.1", 65432])`?

Comment: omg I feel like an idiot. That was it, thanks!

Comment: Why are you calling `tuple()`? Just write `host_port = ("127.0.0.1", 65432)`

Comment: If we're going to be pedantic then: *host_port = '127.0.0.1', 65432* will suffice. The parentheses are irrelevant